# Why SQL Server DateTime, Show AM, but not show PM?

Tags: sql-server, time

See below image,
The UpdateDate column show datetime containing 'AM' text
But the CreateDate show datetime, text 'PM' is not shown.

these 2 columns are auto-generated, and data type is DateTime.
Update Date is :8/19/2010 10:27:20 AM
Create Date is :8/13/2010 1:59:00 PM  [but PM is not shown]

see image:

[image: 1]

If PM not shown, '8/13/2010 1:59:00' will be know as '8/13/2010 1:59:00 AM' by C# Code.

The Server is Sql Server R2.
It's always ok before any today. 
Just last nigh shown as below image.

I think the a bug of Sql Server R2.

Could any one tell me why, and how to avoid it happened once more?

Thank you Every Much!

Comment: `SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109)` will use AM/PM or you can use `SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 114)` for 24h

Answer (score 2):

DateTime doesn't store neither AM nor PM, it's a generic date and time and will be recognized in C# as such regardless.

If you need AM or PM displayed, that's up to how you let C# or whatever render the output - it's not part of how it's stored (unless you store it as a string). Also, if you don't specify how to format the display/output - it can adapt/change depending on what the server locale is or what the client locale is.

*If the screenshot is just from the MS SQL 2008 R2 Management Studio, I've given up on that one for a while, it was incredibly bug-ridden last month.*